# How do I implement dhtmlxScheduler with ASP.NET Core with custom parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core

I implemented dhtmlxScheduler in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and it works fine for me as it is described in [this how to](http://%3Chttps://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/howtostart_dotnet_core.html%3E).

Now I want to add additional parameters like `customerId` (id of the user who just logged in) and `advisorId` (which I want to select from a list). 
How can I do that?

I saw [this](http://%3Chttps://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addevent.html%3E) but no idea how to pass parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question for grammatical corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to add additional parameters like customerId (id of user who just logged in) and advisorId (which i want to select from a list). how can i do that?

You can try to update your `SchedulerEvent` model class to add additional properties, like below.

```
public class SchedulerEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    //Additional properties
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int AdvisorId { get; set; }
}
```

To sync database with model changes, you can do migrations by run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`command.

And you should also update `WebAPIEvent` class, like below.

```
public class WebAPIEvent
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string text { get; set; }
public string start_date { get; set; }
public string end_date { get; set; }

public int customer_id { get; set; }

public int advisor_id { get; set; }

public static explicit operator WebAPIEvent(SchedulerEvent ev)
{
    return new WebAPIEvent
    {
        id = ev.Id,
        text = ev.Name,
        start_date = ev.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),
        end_date = ev.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"),

        customer_id = ev.CustomerId,
        advisor_id = ev.AdvisorId
    };
}

public static explicit operator SchedulerEvent(WebAPIEvent ev)
{
    return new SchedulerEvent
    {
        Id = ev.id,
        Name = ev.text,
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse(ev.start_date,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse(ev.end_date,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),

        CustomerId = ev.customer_id,
        AdvisorId =ev.advisor_id
    };
}
```

Then, you can add new event with `customer_id` and `advisor_id` information on JavaScript client side.

```
scheduler.addEvent({
    start_date: "26-05-2020 09:00",
    end_date:   "27-05-2020 12:00",
    text: "Meeting",
    // userdata
    customer_id : 5,
    advisor_id : 5  
});
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: thanks, it is exactly what i want but can you tell me how can i pass some advisor's id to select combo box?and how to get user's id when logged in. i use Identity in asp.net core.